# How to "pattern match" a template?

Tags: c++, templates

Normally in templates you want to know the entire type, but in my case I need to know more, and want to "break up" the type. Take this example:

```
template <typename Collection<typename T> >
T get_front(Collection const& c)
{
  return c.front();
}
```

How can I achieve that? Note: I need it to to automatically deduce the types, not pass in something like `<std::vector<int>, int>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**: A C++0x way can be found at the end.
**Edit 2**: I'm stupid, and a *way* shorter C++98/03 way than all this traits stuff can be found at the end of the answer.

If you want your function to work for any arbitary standard library container, you need to pull out some Template Guns.

---

The thing is, that the different container take a different amount of template parameters. `std::vector`, `std::deque` and `std::list` for example take 2: the underlying item type `T` and the allocator type `Alloc`. `std::set` and `std::map` on the other hand take 3 and 4 respectively: both have the key type `K`, map takes another value type `V`, then both take a comparator `Compare` type and the allocator type `Alloc`. You can get an overview of all container types supplied by the standard library for example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/).

---

Now, for the Template Guns. We will be using a partially specialized traits metastruct to get the underlying item type. (I use `class` instead of `typename` out of pure preference.)

```
template<class T>
struct ContainerTraits;

// vector, deque, list and even stack and queue (2 template parameters)
template<
    template<class, class> class Container,
    class T, class Other
>
struct ContainerTraits< Container<T,Other> >{
    typedef T value_type;
};

// for set, multiset, and priority_queue (3 template parameters)
template<
    template<class, class, class> class Container,
    class T, class Other1, class Other2
>
struct ContainerTraits< Container<T,Other1,Other2> >{
    typedef T value_type;
};

// for map and multimap (4 template parameters)
template<
    template<class, class, class, class> class Container,
    class Key, class T, class Other1, class Other2
>
struct ContainerTraits< Container<Key,T,Other1,Other2> >{
    typedef Container<Key,T,Other1,Other2> ContainerT;
    // and the map returns pair<const Key,T> from the begin() function
    typedef typename ContainerT::value_type value_type;
};
```

Now that the preparation is done, on to the `get_front` function!

```
template<class Container>
typename ContainerTraits<Container>::value_type
get_front(Container const& c){
    // begin() is the only shared access function
    // to the first element for all standard container (except std::bitset)
    return *c.begin(); 
}
```

Phew! And that's it! A full example can be seen [on Ideone](http://ideone.com/qKmUQ). Of course it would be possible to refine that even further, to the point of returning the actual value that is mapped to a key in a `std::map`, or use container specific access functions, but I was just a bit too lazy to do that. :P

---

**Edit**
A *way* easier C++0x way is using the new trailing-return-type function syntax, of which an example can be found [here on Ideone](http://ideone.com/zjCrr).

---

**Edit 2**
Well, I don't know why, but I totally didn't think of the nested `typedef`s when writing this answer. I'll let the verbose way stay as a reference for traits classes / pattern matching a template. [This](http://ideone.com/skaF1) is the way to do it, it is basically the same I did with the traits classes, but ultimately less verbose.

Comment: +1, you win! definitely the way to go if you want something truly generic.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want both `Collection` and `T` as template parameters.  To do that simply type

```
template< template < typename > class Collection, typename T >
T get_front( Collection< T > const& c )
...
```

The construct `template < typename > class Collection` tells the compiler that `Collection` is a template itself with one parameter.

**Edit**:
As pointed out be [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo), `vector` takes two template parameters, and your templates need to reflect that, i.e.

```
template< template < typename, typename > class Collection, 
          typename T, typename Alloc >
T get_front( Collection< T, Alloc > const& c )
...
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct, and this is exactly what I want -- except it doesn't compile :)

Comment: @user: I assume you wanted to pass a `std::vector`. That particular type takes two template parameters: the type of the items and the type of the allocator. So change that to `template< template<typename, typename> class Collection, typename T, typename Alloc> T get_front(Collection<T,Alloc> const& c)` and you should be fine. If not, what exactly is the error message?

Comment: gcc-4.2.1 on macosx gives the error: "expected 'class' before 'Collection'," implying that here is where the difference between `class` and `typename` is important. It compiles for me fine with the change; I've updated my answer to reflect the change.

Comment: Yup, that was it. It seems to require "class" not "typename". :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do this if you know it's not an associative container.

```
template <typename Collection>
Collection::type_name get_front(Collection const& c)
{
  return c.front();
}
```

Comment: +1, this works well even if the OP needed to use the type inside the function, and in many ways is simpler than my answer.

Comment: Nice and simple, and covers most (I think?) of what OP needs

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as `Collection<T>` is known ahead of time, I think what you want is:

```
template <typename T>
T get_front(Collection<T> const& c)
{
    return c.front();
}
```

The only part that's changing is what `T` is, it's always in a `Collection` (contents, not the container) so you don't have put that as part of the template.

If the container was changing, using `c.front()` could be dangerous. You would need to verify that the collection type had a method `front` that took no parameters and return a `T`.

**Edit:**

If you do need to template `Collection`, then that's more like:

```
template<typename C, typename T>
T get_front(C<T> const & c)
```

I would avoid something that generic if you can, perhaps specializing the function for collections you know will be used, or to a particular class of classes (if possible).

Comment: No, Collection needs to be templated out. i.e. It might be a std::list, std::vector or anything else.. :D

Comment: And as for your edit, I don't think that's valid. C can't be a "partial type" :) i.e. I can't get it to compile, gcc says that's invalid

Comment: Hm. I'd still not recommend that, in general. Maybe the Code Gods have a reason for it being so difficult? :P

Comment: The reason is that std::vector and std::list take two template parameters, the item type and the allocator type. :)

Comment: @Xeo: so they do, don't they? I forgot about that. CWed my answer, so if somebody can fix it, have fun. :)