# How can I refer to the type in a nested template for a parameter argument?

Tags: c++, templates, types

Suppose I have the following definitions

```
template <class T>
class Sequence
{
}
```

E.g
`Sequence<string>` might be an array of strings, similar to `vector<string>`

```
// Now define iterator template
template <class T>
class SequenceIterator
{
}
```

The idea here of course is to be able to create an iterator over some sequence
E.g.

```
SequenceIterator< Sequence<string> > iter1;
SequenceIterator< Sequence<int> > iter2;
```

The question I now have is how to define the member function that would exist inside SequenceIterator and whose purpose is to return the next value in the sequence. Typically I would expect to write that as

```
bool Next(T1 & value); // If the iterator has not finished, set value to the next item
```

However, the `SequenceIterator` has been passed in a templated name already, i.e,  `Sequence<string>` or `Sequence<int>`

So the question is, how do I generically refer to that underlying type (`string` or `int`) so that I can define the Next member function.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways: change the definition of `Sequence` to include

```
typedef T type;
```

or, change the template parameters for `SequenceIterator` to explicitly recognize that `Sequence` is a template itself

```
template< template < class > class Seq, class T >
class SequenceIterator< Seq< T > >
```

and while the instantiation of `SequenceIterator` does not change, you can now access `T` directly.  Thirdly, you can use a [container traits class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440089/how-to-pattern-match-a-template/5440268#5440268) that handles the type deduction for you.  The third option provides the least coupling between `Sequence` and `SequenceIterator`, but, like [Mark said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508746/how-can-i-refer-to-the-type-in-a-nested-template-for-a-parameter-argument/5508805#5508805), the [standard containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) tend to use the first method.

Comment: I love the second option but am having trouble getting it to work. For example, if I write

`template < template <class> class Sequence, class type>`
`class SequenceIterator< Sequence <type> >`
in my code, XCode complains about Explicit specialization of non-template class 'SequenceIterator'.

I must admit it has been many years since I've had to use C++ and the language has changed a lot in the interim, which is why I'm having trouble.

(NB - I can't figure out how to format this comment to break up multiple lines of code INTO multiple lines!)

Answer (score 2):

The standard library solves this by having typedefs within every container. In this case `Sequence<T>` would have a `typedef T value_type;` so you can then use `Sequence<T>::value_type` to refer to that type.

Also, I would highly consider using `operator++` and `operator*` like the standard library so you don't confuse people with a non-standard-like iterator interface.

Comment: Thank you --- I would like to try and make rcollyer's second suggestion work but if I can't, this STL approach is a good option.