# template syntax for containers

Tags: c++, templates

This is what I have now:

```
template<template<typename T> class container, typename T>
inline bool contains( const container<T> &cont, const T &element )
{
    if( cont.size() == 0 )
        return false;

    return( std::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), element) != cont.end() );
}
```

An I'd like to call it like so:

```
std::vector<string> stringvector;
contains( stringvector, "somestring" );
```

I believe this should be possible, but everything I've tried throws up a different error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: Thanks for all the answers already, I was looking too far, but I'm still having problems:

```
template<class container_type, typename T>
inline bool contains(const container_type& c, const T& e)
{
    return !(c.size() && std::find(c.begin(),c.end(),e)!=c.end());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<string> stringvector;
    stringvector.push_back("hello");
    cout << contains( stringvector, string("hello") );
    return 0;
}
```

fails to compile, even without the explicit `string´ constructor:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator, const std::basic_string<char>&)'
```

Comment: Can you give examples of the error messages, to save everyone having to write a (non)-compilable example and trying it for themselves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

STL containers take *two* arguments, one for the contained type and another for the allocator that describes how to obtain memory.

Try this:

```
template<template<typename T, typename Alloc> class container, typename T, typename Alloc>
inline bool contains( const container<T, Alloc > &cont, const T &element )
```

However, this is really a good example of why you should avoid parameterizing algorithms on containers at all. It's best to follow the pattern of `<algorithm>` and only specify iterator type parameters.

```
template< typename Iter, typename T >
inline bool contains( Iter first, Iter last, const T &element )
    { return std::find( first, last, element ) != last; }
```

If you must ask for a container, don't bother to specify what the container looks like. Just assume it has the interface you want. This is the easiest thing for you, and the most flexible thing for the user.

```
template< typename Cont, typename T >
inline bool contains( Cont const &cont, T const &element )
    { return std::find( cont.begin(), cont.end(), element ) != cont.end(); }
```

Comment: Isn't the second template argument provided with a default value (ie the `std::allocator<T>`? I've never had to specify an allocator anywhere?

Comment: Wow, with your code I get `no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator, const std::basic_string<char>&)'`. Maybe it's getting too late here...

Comment: your last code sample has undeclared `last` ;-) I believe you meant to change it to cont.end()

Comment: @rubenvb: Yes, there is a default value, but that does not affect which parameter specifications are matched when passing a template template parameter.

Comment: Your updated code causes the same error message :( "no matching function call".

Comment: @rubenvb: Here's a working context; I didn't change anything in the first snippet: http://ideone.com/nmcOL - did you `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: <smacks himself on the forehead> wow, `#include <algorithm>`. Now why didn't I think of that... Time to wrap up for tonight I think, I'm getting tired :)

Comment: @rubenvb: Note that above only works for vector, deque, list, stack and queue. Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440089/how-to-pattern-match-a-template/5440268#5440268) of mine for a nice container_traits example. :)

Comment: This is subtly wrong... the standard allows for implementors to provide any number of arguments as long as they get default values. What it means is that you can use `std::vector<type>` or `std::vector<type,allocator>`, but that the implementation is not required to provide a template with exactly two parameters. A compliant implementation could provide `std::vector<type,allocator,other_trait>`, for optimization purposes. STL containers are tricky to this respect...

Comment: @David: Do you have a reference for that? It sounds plausible, but I have to wonder. (The code listings are a grey area.) Anyway, it's a bad assumption because restricting an interface to the standard containers is counterproductive when the object is flexibility. (Also, many like to treat `string` as a container, and it does take 3 parameters.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I had read it a couple of times, and I even recall that once I was pointed to some sentence in the standard, but after looking for it I did not find. Then I googled, and I googled more... finally, it seems that I was incorrect and that implementations **cannot** add extra arguments with default values. Funny enough, I found the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469743/standard-library-containers-with-additional-optional-template-parameters) here in SO. Thanks for doubting, I have learnt something new.

Comment: @David: Wow, thanks for the research! Of course, there are plenty of other ways to pass more parameters, and knowingly breaking debatably-compliant code would still have been within the letter but against the spirit of the law…

Answer (score 3):

Why not just

```
template<class container_type,typename T>
inline bool contains(const container_type& c,const T& e) {
    return !(c.size() && std::find(c.begin(),c.end(),e)!=c.end());
}
```

Comment: The check for `size()` is not necessary. - If you must, `!c.empty()` would be better (with some implementations `std::list.size()` has linear complexity).

Comment: UncleBens, so I thought but borrowed it from the original. I'd go for `.empty()` if anything.

Comment: +1 Nice, simple *and correct* which is something that the accepted answer is not.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
template <class T> 
bool contains(const T & cont, const typename T::value_type & elem)
{
   return( std::find(cont.begin(), cont.end(), elem) != cont.end() );
}
```

Most standard Containers have a `value_type` typedef which simplifies this.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler than that... just consider the container and the contained element type as template parameters...

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<typename C, typename E>
bool contains(const C& c, const E& e)
{
    return std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), e) != c.end();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> V;
    std::list<std::string> L;
    std::set<std::string> S;

    V.push_back("Foo"); L.push_back("Foo"); S.insert("Foo");
    V.push_back("Bar"); L.push_back("Bar"); S.insert("Bar");

    std::cout << contains(V, "Foo") << std::endl;
    std::cout << contains(L, "Foo") << std::endl;
    std::cout << contains(S, "Foo") << std::endl;

    std::cout << contains(V, "Baz") << std::endl;
    std::cout << contains(L, "Baz") << std::endl;
    std::cout << contains(S, "Baz") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note however that for example in the code above I'm using `contains` also with `std::set`, where `std::find` is not a smart way to search things (`std::set::find` can do better than O(n)).

Comment: I think I remember a `std::set::find` calling  `lower_bound`, which has the better complexity. (GCC 4.5)

Comment: Exactly my point; but `std::find` is just given an iterator so it must walk it instead. I was just saying that `contains` is going to be highly inefficient in that case.